# KDB/Q Websocket example, getting `badmsg error: How to serialize my data when sending it over to my KDB server?

Tags: python, websocket, kdb

Lately, I've been trying to stream data from KDB to python.
I'm now using websockets and have gone through the doc https://code.kx.com/q/wp/kdb_and_websockets.pdf

On the python side, I've been trying ws4py, autobahn and websocket-client.

All do work fine, essentially my problem resides in the format of the message sent to the server to subscribe to the feed.

A little (open source) example:

```
class DummyClient(WebSocketClient):
    def opened(self):
        self.send(*what should I put here?*, binary=True)

    def closed(self, code, reason=None):
        print("Closed down", code, reason)

    def received_message(self, m):
        # not yet implemented

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        ws = DummyClient('ws://host:port/', protocols=['http-only', 'chat'])
        ws.connect()
        ws.run_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        ws.close()
```

When opening, I'm supposed to subscribe to the feed by calling the server function loadPage.
I've tried different things when to encode the list containing the function name and the argument, without success.

What I've tried:

np.array("['loadPage',[]]").tobytes()

"['loadPage',[]]".encode('utf8')

json formating

hexadecimal formating

Any help would be much appreciated!

Best,
Yael

Comment: Apologies if this is a silly (and/or unhelpful) question but why are you trying to stream the data via websockets? Why not stream data directly from kdb to python using something like qPython, it handles serialisation etc https://github.com/exxeleron/qPython

Comment: Hi Terry, this is not silly at all. let's say that it's a requirement that I have as a lot of clients are web based and support websockets. servers and clients are all going to communicate via websocket, I do not want to have a tcp/ip connection if I can avoid it

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'll need to do in this case is define `.z.ws` in your kdb server. This function will be called with whatever you pass over the websocket as an argument, so for example if you defined `.z.ws` like so:

```
.z.ws:{show x}
```

and then send a message over the WebSocket like so:

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1234")
ws.send("Hello World")
```

This will be output in your kdb session e.g.

```
 λ q
KDB+ 3.6 2018.06.14 Copyright (C) 1993-2018 Kx Systems
w64/ 4(16)core 8082MB jonat laptop-o8a8co1o 10.255.252.249 EXPIRE 2019.05.21 jonathon.mcmurray@aquaq.co.uk KOD #4160315

q).z.ws:{show x}
q)\p 1234
q)"Hello World"
```

So in your case if you want to call `loadPage`, it might be as simple as defining `.z.ws` like so:

```
.z.ws:loadPage
```

Then whatever you pass over the socket will be passed into `loadPage` (note this is will not update if you change `loadPage` elsewhere, you can instead use `.z.ws:{loadPage x}` if you need to be able to update it dynamically). For a niladic function, this will just ignore whatever is passed in

Comment: Thank you for this, I'll give it a shot asap :)